# Не устаналивается приложение собранное со своим ключом

Tags: android, generate

Создал свой ключ app.keystore, пытаюсь собрать debug для проверки на телефоне, но приложение не устанавливается, если собирает студия со своим по умолчанию ключом, то запускается. Из-за чего такая проблема может возникать?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.personal.anton.notes"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Телепатический канал нарушен. Опишите подробнее ошибку при установке. Собирается apk без ошибок? Или вы в gradle для debug указали подписывание ключом и сразу устанавливаете на устройство через adb или Run App?

Comment: Собирается без ошибок, "приложение не установлено" - такое сообщение.

Comment: Так может оно не установлено и его надо установить?

Comment: Такое сообщение получаю во время установки!

Comment: @АнтонЛялин, собираете через Build -> Generate Signed APK?

Comment: @A.Shakhov Конечно, через него и пописываю своим ключом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В тестовом режиме вы генерируете `debug`:

`Build/Build APK(s)` система подписывает его своим ключом.

А в готовом релизе вы используете `release`:

`Generated Singet APK...` его подписываете вы сами.

Если вы установите `debug`, а потом захотите установить `release` то приложение не установится, так как произойдет конфликт в совпадении пакетов приложения. Перед установкой `release` удаляйте с девайса `debug`.

P.S. если у вас на девайсе установлено приложение, которое вы подписали сами, и вы через AS устанавливаете `debug`, то AS предлагает удалить `release`. А обратную процедуру нужно делать в ручную, то есть как и было сказано выше, перед установкой `release` вы в ручную должны удалить `debug` версию.

Comment: Я подписывал только debug, перед установкой обычно AS выдает ошибку, если установлено приложение, но другой версии, из-за различий в ключах. С release я не пробовал, ставил только debug, но проблема что она не хочет устанавливаться, удалял с телефона, пересобирал проект и так далее, но все счетно.

Answer (score 1):

- Выполните задачу Tasks -> build -> clean модуля app (во вкладке Gradle справа)
- Сделайте чистку проекта (вкладка Build -> Clean Project)
- Пересоберите проект (вкладка Build -> Rebuild Project)

Так же ознакомьтесь с [официальной документацией](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) на эту тему

---

P.S. обычно debug-сборки не подписывают, это нужно для release-ных сборок для идентификации разработчика, если выкладываете в Play Маркет

Comment: Не помогло, такая же ошибка. Если так, то ладно, но все же, то работает, то нет

Comment: @АнтонЛялин, у вас до установки подписанного приложения на устройстве была установлена старая неподписанная версия? Если да, то удалите её и попробуйте заново

Comment: удалил старую версию

Comment: @АнтонЛялин, при сборке подписанного apk на последнем шаге внизу для Signature Versions установите обе галочки - и на V1, и на V2

Comment: Выдал ошибку, 
"The security strength of SHA-1 digest algorithm is not sufficient for this key size
"

Comment: @АнтонЛялин, что-то не так с вашим ключом. Дополнил ответ документацией

Comment: Очень странно, но помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Настраивали ли Вы proguard? Возможно настройки для дебага и релиза отличаются. Попробуйте перезагрузить устройство, иногда такое тоже помогает.

Comment: В progurd смотрел, нет ничего, что могло бы быть проблемой, к тому же, AS debug со своим ключом запускается, а с с моим нет. Читайте внимательнее, все это я описал выше.